# Insert PDF files in RDLC report as an annex

Tags: sql-server, wpf, pdf, reporting-services

I am developing a WPF application in VB. Net and I'm using SQL Server Reporting to create my reports.

I have a report that contains the specifications for a machine and I would add the PDF file that contains additional information to report and then print it.

Is it possible to dynamically add PDF files in a RDLC report?

Or is there a way to solve this problem

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont think that reports server has any inbuilt support for pdf's. You might be able to buy one, but i think i would save the pdf's as jpegs and just put those in the report instead

Comment: That's what I think. 

So the only problem with the conversion of PDF to images is the loss of quality.

Thank you